# Switch value of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I switch the value of the objects in javascript for example I have these codes

```
var sampleQuery = [
{   
    'query' : 'potato',
    'status' : ''
},{   
    'query' : 'orange',
    'status' : 'and'
},{   
    'query' : 'farm',
    'status' : 'or'
},{   
    'query' : 'seed',
    'status' : 'or'
},{
    'query' : 'produce',
    'status' : 'and'
},{   
    'query' : 'grape',
    'status' : 'or'
}
]
```

what I want is to change the value of "status: and" to "status: or" if there's "status: or" after "status: and". and if theres no following "or" "and" would still the same. it would look something like these

```
var sampleQuery = [
{   
    'query' : 'potato',
    'status' : ''
},{   
    'query' : 'orange',
    'status' : 'or'
},{   
    'query' : 'farm',
    'status' : 'and'
},{   
    'query' : 'seed',
    'status' : 'and'
},{
    'query' : 'produce',
    'status' : 'or'
},{   
    'query' : 'grape',
    'status' : 'and'
}
]
```

I tried using substring but I'm pretty new to javascript and have no idea how can I do it.

Comment: So why does it look like you change the status of `or` to `and`?  Be sure you have all your rules clearly defined

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a loop and check the status property for a match with either "and" or "or".

```
for(let i = 0; i < sampleQuery.length; i++) {
    let curr = sampleQuery[i];
    if(curr.status === "and") {
        curr.status = "or";
    } else if(curr.status === "or") {
        curr.status = "and";
    }
}
```

Another way with forEach syntax:

```
sampleQuery.forEach((ele) => {
    if(ele.status === "and") {
        ele.status = "or";
    } else if(ele.status === "or") {
        ele.status = "and";
    }
});
```